# Mincer-Zarnowitz: High Wald statistic, although intercept near 0 and slope near 1?

Tags: forecasting, f-test

I have regressed the following points with OLS

[image]

the intercept is -0,085 while the slope is 1,008. So highly dependent. So far so good.

The t-statistics for the intercept are -2,84 and 27,87 for the slope... Both showing significance.

Now when I use the Wald test as

$Wald  statistic = c'*inv(Var)*c $

where $c$ represents the vector with the regression coefficients and $Var$ is the covariance matrix of the coefficients. For convenience I test the null if both, intercept and slope is equal to zero after I reduced the y values with the x values. So both values in $c$ are close to zero.

However, with above formula I get a Wald statistic of 2.2431e+03 .. So I need to reject the null...

The reason is actually, that the variances and covariances are extremely low and inversing leads to huge values... So it doesn't matter how low $c$ is, the Wald statistic is high... I don't get the point here. Higher variances would allow me to not reject the null. This does not reasonable for me.

This could be a reason... the errors I highly autocorrelated...

[image]

Comment: by the way: when I use HAC consistent covariance-variance matrix, the wald statistic drops to 343... still high

Comment: I believe the apparent significant in your p-values is grossly inflated due to the obvious and strong serial correlation in the data.  It looks you have bivariate *time series* data and that you should be using appropriate time series models to analyze them.

Comment: correct yes. I found that if I increase the lags for calculating HAC consistent estimates the Wald statistic dropping. I have huge autocorrelation in the data... This is mainly because of the concept how I have to forecast. I am forecasting 252 days ahead. The are usually all very bad and autocorrelated... I have added the autocorr plot.. Any idea how to overcome this? Use HAC consistent errors with 250 lags???

Comment: For nonstationary time series ARIMA models can be used to remive trends and arrive at a statistionary sequence where the autocorrelation function drops off exponentially once the model is transformed. That then can be can used to forecast.  See one of the editions of Box and Jenkins  "Time Series Analysis: Forecasting and Control".

Comment: @whuber: May I ask, how did you saw only from the x-y plot that they are highly autocorralted? Just for interest... thanks

Comment: The points appear to track along an (erratic) curve in the X-Y plane.  This indicates that the two values observed at one time will tend to be very close to the two values observed at nearby times--and this is what autocorrelation measures.

Comment: @MichaelChernick: Thanks, I red the source. Simple OLS regression seems to be dangerous when using by presence of autocorrelation. However, I don't understand the point of trying to "press" something to a direction which does not exist. As I only need to describe the stats, I can't change the facts how the regression coefficients are... HAC consistent covariance sounds reasonable, though..